# Find all possible stacktraces for a function

Tags: python, ide, code-analysis, static-analysis

First of all, I'm not sure I'm asking for something that is doable.
Sometimes, when I have to do some refactoring in a large codebase, I need to change the output or even the signature of a certain function. Before than I do that, I have to make sure that that output is handled correctly by the other functions that are going to call it.
The way I do it is by searching for the function name, say `get_timezone_from user` and then I see that function is used by two other functions called `format` and `change_timezone_for_user`. And I start looking for where those two functions are used etc... until I end up with a graph where each path looks like a stacktrace.

There are two problems.
The first one is that doing this manually is pretty time consuming.
The second is that when I look at all occurrences of a function name like `format`, I will often find occurences of the word `format` in different contexts. It can be a comment or even another function defined somewhere else.

My question is simple:
Is there an IDE or a tool that allows to find where in your code a certain function is called? Even better would be if that tool is recursive so that it draws the whole graph.

I'm trying to achieve this in Python if that helps.

Comment: Since you can pass your function around to other functions or alias it to different names, etc ... I find it extremely unlikely that there will be a tool which could get this 100% correct.

Comment: I suspected that... You still have to declare aliases in the same file where you use that function so it shouldn't be hard to automate the equivalence between a function and its alias.
As for your first concern, it should also be feasible to add in the stacktrace functions where my initial function was passed around.

Comment: If you have a comprehensive test suite, you could decorate the function and dump stack traces whenever it is called. Code not covered is obviously a problem.

Comment: You would need to cover every single possibility of calling that function in your test suite...

Comment: Static code analysis can get seriously out of hand with a language like python. Imagine you storing one of two functions in a variable, based on user input, and later call whatever is stored.